# What is meant by "analog function" in this context?

Tags: analog

I sometimes encounter this term like [here](https://www.eenewsanalog.com/content/implementing-analog-functions-rugged-rad-hard-fpgas/page/0/1).

Do they mean analog signals when they write "analog functions"?

Comment: They mean "functionality".

Comment: functionality or features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean "functionality".

Basically, a digital function is one where the voltage levels are well defined to mean a number -- almost always a 1 or 0, but search on "four level memory" and "trinary logic" for exceptions.  Digital logic defines some voltage range (usually close to zero volts) as '0', some other voltage range (usually close to the supply voltage in CMOS, but it varies) as '1', and some range in the middle as "not guaranteed".

So AND gates, OR gates, memory, etc. are digital functions.

The term "analog" has become a misnomer -- originally it meant something along the lines of "electronic analogy".  Now it means that the input or output or both of a circuit is a continuous range of voltages -- so an analog amplifier might take any voltage in the range -0.1V to +0.1V and amplify it up to the range -5V to +5V.  An analog filter would use resistors, capacitors, and active elements to implement some sort of frequency-selective filter, without ever putting the signal into the digital domain.

That article appears at first glance (I didn't read it deeply) to be about using parts of the FPGA that have well-defined analog behavior as building blocks in mixed-signal (i.e., analog and digital) functions like analog to digital converters.

Answer (score -1):

They mean functionality or features.

**Update**

A comparator circuit is an analog function in a circuit.

A voltage summing circuit is an analog function.

Comment: Can you give specific examples as well?

Comment: @pnatk See update.